# Is AirDrop Icon not suppose to show anymore?

Tags: macos, icon, airdrop

I just updated to macOS Monterey. I use a MBP 2019 16" and I have Show AirDrop in menu bar enabled.  The space is showing empty where the icon use to be.  But, if I move my cursor to the spot and click, the airdrop icon will appear.

How can I make it be visible always as before?  Maybe this is expected behavior in Monterey or bug? 1st screen shows option enabled then the 2nd is if I move the cursor to the spot and click, it appears.  Only to disappear once I move the cursor and click.

EDIT:  I just restarted in safe mode and it appears only to go away again on restart.

EDIT 2: so maybe the thread needs to be re-titled...  I add now a screen shot of safe mode menu bar compared to regular start up in pic 4.  There is a menu bar color difference in safe mode which allows me to see the icon.  But it changes when un regular start up.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

Comment: Shows properly on my MBP, what have you tried so far? Restart, disable and enable,...?

Comment: So I restarted in regular mode.  Same behavior. I disabled and re-enabled to show. Same.  BUT, just now I restarted in safe mode and it appeared only to go away again on restart.

Comment: I also removed the wifi icon and everything shifts to the right - including the blank spot where the airdrop should be. And shifts back to the left when I reenable the wifi icon.

Answer (score 1):

Found it - Accessibility, display, reduce transparency....

[image]